# How to get attributes in CkEditors in react?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

<CKEditor
editor={ClassicEditor}
data={`<h1 id="ckedr">Hello from CKEditor&nbsp;5's decoupled editor!</h1>`}
onReady={(editor) => {
editorRef.current = editor;
}}
onChange={(event, editor) => {
const htmlContent = editor.getData();
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlContent, "text/html");
console.log(doc);
console.log(editor.getData());
}}
/>

When I am consoling the editor.getData() why I am not getting the output  Hello from CKEditor 5's decoupled editor! instead my getting

## Hello from CKEditor 5's decoupled editor!

What is solution for that